# cksum files using substituted variable string as a pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, eval

Can I avoid `eval` in the below example or is there no other way?
The list of files on variable is dynamic, and I want to cksum all of them.
There are many other files in the directory, but they should be ignored.

```
$ Z="file1 file4"
$ echo ${Z//\ /,}
file1,file4
$ echo {${Z//\ /,}}
{file1,file4}
$ cksum {file1,file4}
927007485 136284 file1
2748059092 136286 file4
$ cksum {${Z//\ /,}}
cksum: {file1,file4}: No such file or directory
$ eval cksum {${Z//\ /,}}
927007485 136284 file1
2748059092 136286 file4
```

Comment: Are the filenames hard-coded into the `Z` variable? Consider hard-coding them into an array, instead, or showing a glob pattern that would pick up all & only the files you're interested in.

Comment: i'm curious, why don't you use directly `cksum $Z` ?
it works for me.

Comment: ... until you have a file named `space here` or `f*` or `file?` in which case shell globbing get involved.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549

Answer (score 3):

Using an array instead of a string:

```
files=( file1 file2 "filename with spaces" file50 "*my* file" )

cksum "${files[@]}"
```

Note that every double quote above is important, especially if you have filenames with spaces or filename globbing characters in them.

Comment: For consideration, *if* the filenames are hard-coded into `Z`, you could: `set -f; files=($Z); set +f`, then use the array.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, that would probably work unless the files have spaces in their names.

Comment: Indeed; I almost wrote up a separate answer, starting with `*If* you have a *space-separated* list of filenames in $Z`, but realized it was an assumption, thus my comment on the Q.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why `cksum {${Z//\ /,}}` did not work as you expected:

1. according the the bash [order of substitutions/expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions), brace expansion occurs *before* parameter substitions
2. however, [it is documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) that "To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not considered eligible for brace expansion." -- so bash does not perform brace expansion here.
3. then the shell eventually gets to parameter substitution, and the command is expanded to `cksum {file1,file4}`
4. the shell does not go back and re-do the list of expansions, so we don't get brace expansion again: we are left with the single word "{file1,file4}"
5. and there is no such file.

When you introduce `eval` into the mix, you are explicitly asking the shell to go through the list of expansions once more. *Now* we can get brace expansion on the command `cksum {file1,file4}` and you get the checksums for those 2 files.